# Why doesn't my web-scraping code work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the airplane arrivals from a website with Python 2.7, and export it to excel, but something is wrong with my code:

```
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')

url = "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/bud/arrivals"

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

data = soup.find('div', { "class" : "row cnt-schedule-table"})
print data
```

I need the contents of the div with class `row cnt-schedule table`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the `soup` or `page` variables after they've been set? This might provide you with some clues.

Comment: you have to specify a *parser* for BeautifulSoup, so change to : `soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')`

Comment: i changed to "soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')" but still not working.

Comment: check the value of `page` variable , it should not be `None` . It shoud have some html

Comment: this is not None. in this "row cnt-schedule-table" there are the relevant informations.

Comment: i see you undervoted my question, but i cant understand why, if you cant give me a correct answer...

Comment: please outline _what_ is the issue with your code.
If it's an error, then add it to your question

Comment: What prints out when you do this?

Comment: `page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5'}).content`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to get data from a JavaScript loaded data-set.  Instead of loading from the page directly you'll need to mimic the requests for the data that the page is making to populate it.